# Structured Streaming kafka spark java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/internal/Logging

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I find many FAQ about this problem,but not work .

I am a newbie for java and bigdata, java dependency management is terrible for me.You have to guess which package and version should be used and which package will conflict if the Third-party libraries don't tell you anything

I want to parse json data from kafka topic and save to hbase.

main code

```java
package com.yizhisec.bigdata;

import com.yizhisec.bigdata.model.Traffic;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.ForeachWriter;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class KafkaStructStream {

    private Dataset<Row> initStructKafka() throws IOException {
        Properties kafkaProp = Config.getProp();
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("Kafka")
                .master("local[2]")
                .getOrCreate();
        return spark.readStream().format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaProp.getProperty("kafka.broker.list"))
                .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SSL")
                .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", Config.getPath(Config.KAFKA_JKS))
                .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password", kafkaProp.getProperty("kafka.jks.passwd"))
                .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
                .option("subscribe", kafkaProp.getProperty("kafka.topic"))
                .load();
    }

    private void run() {
        Dataset<Row> df = null;
        try {
            df = initStructKafka();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        df.printSchema();
        Dataset<Traffic> ds = df.as(ExpressionEncoder.javaBean(Traffic.class));

        StreamingQuery query = ds.writeStream().foreach(new ForeachWriter<Traffic>() {
            @Override
            public boolean open(long partitionId, long epochId) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void process(Traffic value) {
                System.out.println(value);
            }

            @Override
            public void close(Throwable errorOrNull) {

            }
        }).start();

//        StreamingQuery query = ds.writeStream().format("console")
//                .trigger(Trigger.Continuous("2 seconds"))
//                .start();

        try {
            query.awaitTermination();
        } catch (StreamingQueryException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KafkaStructStream k = new KafkaStructStream();
        k.run();
    }

}
```

Traffic.class

```java
public class Traffic {
    private Long guid;
    private int time;
    private int end_time;
    private String srcip;
    private String srcmac;
    private int srcport;
    private String destip;
    private String destmac;
    private int destport;
    private String proto;
    private String appproto;
    private Long upsize;
    private Long downsize;

    getter and setter
}
```

dependency

```xml
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <spark.version>2.4.4</spark.version>
        <scala.version>2.11.12</scala.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--        kafka-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

ERROR

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/internal/Logging
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.yizhisec.bigdata.KafkaStructStream.initStructKafka(KafkaStructStream.java:20)
    at com.yizhisec.bigdata.KafkaStructStream.run(KafkaStructStream.java:37)
    at com.yizhisec.bigdata.KafkaStructStream.main(KafkaStructStream.java:76)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.internal.Logging
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 15 more
```

---

## Solution

After some try. Finally, I found the solution. A **very silly default option** waste me a day. I am too stupid to find the class has existed, but import failed in running time because **Provided scope**
[image]

Comment: Spent about 1hr trying to debug this... thank you

Answer (score 2):

> You have to guess which package and version should be used

Not really guessing... Spark 2.4.x is built with Scala 2.12, and that is documented. Your POM says Scala 2.11.x

You should also remove the `spark-streaming-kafka_2.11` and Kafka dependencies because you're using structured streaming, which requires the `sql-kafka` one, but it's not provided, so remove the scope tag

And if you always use `<version>${spark.version}</version>`, then you shouldn't have to guess

Sidenote: there are Spark Hbase libraries, so you shouldn't need to write your own foreach writer